# Scrapy and Pycharm - Stange import error - No module named [insert name of scrapyproject here]

Tags: python, module, scrapy, pycharm

Hi Stackoverflow Community

I encountered the following issue. I have a scrapy project which I added to my project:

```
-.idea
-associate
-core
-scrapyproject
   -- scrapyproject_one
     --- spiders
       ---- __iniy.py__
       ---- dmoz_spider.py
   -- __init__.py
   -- items.py
   -- pipelines.py
   -- settings.py
```

My dmoz_spider.py looks like this:

```
import scrapy

from scrapyproject.scrapyproject_one import items

class DmozSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "dmoz"
    allowed_domains = ["dmoz.org"]
    start_urls = [
       "http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Books/",
        "http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Resources/"
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for sel in response.xpath('//ul/li'):
            item = items.ScrapyprojectItem()
            item['title'] = sel.xpath('a/text()').extract()
            item['link'] = sel.xpath('a/@href').extract()
            item['desc'] = sel.xpath('text()').extract()
            yield item
```

But when I navigate into the scrapyproject> folder and execute

```
scrapy dmoz crawl
```

I receive the following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\runpy.py", line 170, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Scripts\scrapy.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\scrapy\cmdline.py", line 108, in execute
    settings = get_project_settings()
  File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\project.py", line 60, in get_proj
ect_settings
    settings.setmodule(settings_module_path, priority='project')
  File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\scrapy\settings\__init__.py", line 282, in set
  File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\project.py", line 60, in g
et_project_settings
    settings.setmodule(settings_module_path, priority='project')
  File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\scrapy\settings\__init__.py", line 282,
  File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\scrapy\cmdline.py", line 108, in
execute
    settings = get_project_settings()
  File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\project.py", line 60
, in get_project_settings
    settings.setmodule(settings_module_path, priority='project')
  File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\scrapy\settings\__init__.py", lin
e 282, in setmodule
ne 60, in get_project_settings
    settings.setmodule(settings_module_path, priority='project')
  File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\scrapy\settings\__init__.py"
, line 282, in setmodule
ct.py", line 60, in get_project_settings
    settings.setmodule(settings_module_path, priority='project')
  File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\scrapy\settings\__
init__.py", line 282, in setmodule
    module = import_module(module)
  File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126
 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 944, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 956, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ImportError: No module named 'scrapyproject'
```

Wondering whether anyone would know how I might be able to approach this. Any advice would be highly appreciated!

M

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All right, I figured it out.

What I needed to do was to declare my 'spiderproject' folder as a 'Sources folder' in PyCharm.

You can do that by going to File>Settings>Project:[Project Name]>Project Structure.

Select the level 1 project folder of your scrapy project (in this case 'spiderproject') and Mark as Sources by clicking the blue Folder at the top.

Then go to your spider and

```
 from spiderproject.items import [whatever you named your item class you defined in items.py ]
```

Hope this helps.

M